# C# How to find all the indexes in a list where a property equals a value

Tags: c#

I'm running into memory issues because I have a collection that continues to grow.  What I need to do is only keep about 15 items of each occurence in a list, so my idea is to find all the occurences where a value is equal to a supplied argument and then remove that index (reverse of course).  My question, is how do you find all occurences?  Below finds 1 occurence.

```
public static void CleanTrackers()
        {
            foreach (var ticker in tickersToWatchForAHPM)
            {
                var fullTrackers = QouteTrackers.FindIndex(x => x.Ticker == ticker);

            }

        }
```

Comment: [Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Database_languages).

Comment: Can you explain better?  You want to find all occurrences of X and remove some X from a list?

Comment: A List may not be the best data structure here...but to answer your question, you probably need to traverse the entire list to get all the indexes, or if you prefer keep using FindIndex starting at the last index found (plus one), which seems little better.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what a ticker is here ... if its just a string, why would there be duplicates? i.e., ['GOOG', 'META', 'MS', 'GOOG', 'GOOG'] -- what good are the two extra GOOG's doing for you?

Comment: If I had to do that, I'd make the QuoteTracker do the housekeeping on insert.

Comment: Also: what's the access profile? Will read:write be 1:1 or one heavily exceeding the other?

Comment: ▲ for @fildor comment. After posting a previous answer last night which _cleaned up an existing gigantic list_, literally my first waking thought was, "We can't let it get that big in the first place." Let me make it up to you by revising my answer. Credit goes to Fildor.

Comment: I've also added the alternative database implementation per comment by @dr.null.

Answer (score 1):

Fildor's comment is spot on. To ensure that the data structure doesn't become too enormous, use a `Queue<TickerModel>` with a `MAX` (e.g. of 15 per your spec) and make dictionary of queues by ticker symbol to retrieve the price queue for a given symbol.

```
class ThrottledTickDict
{
    const int MAX = 15;
    private Dictionary<string, Queue<TickerModel>> _data = new Dictionary<string, Queue<TickerModel>>();
    public TickerModel[] this[string key] => 
        _data.TryGetValue(key, out var symbolQueue) ?
        symbolQueue.ToArray() :
        new TickerModel[0];
    public void Add(TickerModel model)
    {
        if(!_data.ContainsKey(model.Ticker))
        {
            _data[model.Ticker] = new Queue<TickerModel>();
        }
        if(_data[model.Ticker].Count == MAX)
        {
            _ = _data[model.Ticker].Dequeue();
        }
        _data[model.Ticker].Enqueue(model);
    }
}
```

Where:

```
class TickerModel
{
    public string Ticker { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string? Price { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Ticker} [{Timestamp}] {Price}";
}
```

---

**Simulation**

Up to 15 quotes are listed, from oldest to newest with an eye toward some kind of rolling chart visualization where the series would plot from left to right.

[image: simulation]

###### Console code

```
var limitedData = new ThrottledTickDict();
Console.Title = "QuoteTracker";

// Simulate a subscribed ticker stream.
new MockTickerGenerator().TickerChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(sender is MockTickerGenerator quoteStream)
    {
        limitedData.Add(e);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Ticker} - {limitedData[e.Ticker].Length} quotes");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, limitedData[e.Ticker].Select(_ => _)));
    }
};
Console.ReadKey();
```

Where:

```
class MockTickerGenerator
{
    Random _rando = new Random(1);
    private Dictionary<string, double> _lastPrice = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    public MockTickerGenerator() => _ = GenerateRandomTickStream();
    List<string> Symbols { get; } =
        new List<string> { "AAA", "BBBB", "CCC", "DDDD", "EEE", "FFFF", "GGG", "HHHH", };
    private async Task GenerateRandomTickStream()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var ticker = Symbols[_rando.Next(8)];
            if (!_lastPrice.ContainsKey(ticker))
            {
                _lastPrice[ticker] = 10 + 90 * _rando.NextDouble();
            }
            var price = Math.Max(1.0, _lastPrice[ticker] + (0.5 - _rando.NextDouble()) * 2);
            _lastPrice[ticker] = price;
            TickerChanged?.Invoke(this, new TickerModel
            {
                Ticker = ticker,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Price = $"{price:f2}",
            });
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5 + _rando.NextDouble()));
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<TickerModel>? TickerChanged;
}
```

---

**Database Version**

Per Dr. Null's comment, the same scheme could be implemented using a database, either in memory (as shown here) or on disk.

```cs
class ThrottledTickDict
{
    public ThrottledTickDict() => Database.CreateTable<TickerModel>();
    const int MAX = 15;

    //  <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    SQLiteConnection Database { get; } = new SQLiteConnection(":memory:");
    public TickerModel[] this[string key] =>
        Database
        .Query<TickerModel>($"select * from {nameof(TickerModel)} where {nameof(TickerModel.Ticker)}='{key}'")        
        .OrderByDescending(_=>_.Timestamp)
        .ToArray();
    public void Add(TickerModel model)
    {
        var existing = this[model.Ticker];
        for (int i = 0; i <= existing.Length - MAX; i++) 
        {
            Database.Delete(existing[i]);
        }
        if(1 != Database.Insert(model))
        {
            Debug.Fail("The operation is expected to succeed");
        }
    }
}
```

Where

```
class TickerModel
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    public string Ticker { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string? Price { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Ticker} [{Timestamp}] {Price}";
}
```